# In App Purchase on iOS doesn't fetch product in Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, swift4

I am trying to fetch an in-app-purchase from App Store Connect like this:

```
private let kOneMonthSubscriptionId = "DOUBLESPEEDENERGY"
func loadProducts() {
    let identifiers = Set([kOneMonthSubscriptionId])
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: identifiers)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
    {
        loadProducts()
    }

}

extension homeVC: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if response.products.count > 0 {
        print("Purchasable products available!")
        // 1. Save the SKProduct's so you could let the user make a purchase
        // 2. Update the UI - it lets you change the product prices without updating the app
    } else {
        print("No purchasable products available.")
        // This might happen when your product identifiers are incorrect or your in-app purchases products weren't processed on iTunes Connect yet
    }
}
```

Please have a look if their is anything wrong with my code, I really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: you are using same bundle id which is created in your developer account?

Comment: Yes i'm use same bundle id. @Dharmesh

Comment: @Dharmesh client billing details is not approve. and it's not work for me 

thanks for help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you don't have a banking method for In-App Purchases setup in App Store Connect (Agreements, Tax and Banking section (Paid Apps)), if you don't then your app cannot access the In-App Purchase service because it doesn't know where to make payments even though you are in a sandbox environment.

If this doesn't help have a look at some other possibilities why it's not working:

- You did not use an explicit App ID.
- You did not use the Provisioning
  Profile associated with your explicit App ID.
- You did not use the
  correct product identifier in your code.
- You did not clear your In App Purchase products for sale in iTunes Connect.
- You might have modified your products, but these changes are not yet available to all the App Store servers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it's help full me @OkiRules